# an analogue of ncurses for JRuby running in browser?

Tags: ruby, jruby, ncurses, roguelike

I want to run in the browser  a ruby application using ncurses. 
To do that, I can use JRuby; but what do I replace ncurses with ?

I am thinking of running JRuby as an applet as decribed [here](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/samples/irb-applet.html). I have also found some Jave 
code [1](http://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/gpmjc/whats_a_good_pseudocurseslike_ui_library/) that does ncurses-like interface but I do not know how do I integrate it with JRuby.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be very hard to get something similar to ncurses in JRuby due to this particular issue that's been plaguing Java for ages. Please post in this thread if you'd like to see this fixed in the future.

http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view%5Fbug.do?bug%5Fid=6351276